# When I refresh my page, there is a 50% chance the colour scheme will be different, how with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my page to have two possible outcomes (50% chance) when page is refreshed/loaded. I know this has to be done with math random, but how?

Here is my current code for my 1st page outcome:

```
<html>
<head>

<title> Flow Test </title>

<script>


</script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Some Flow of Control</h1>
<p>This text is a random combination of a foreground colour and background colour</p>
<p>In this case it's black on white</p>
<p> Signed </p>

<img src="bonw.gif">
</body>

</html>
```

This pages background will be white with black text. But for my second outcome I want it to have a black background with white text, and displaying the other image I have (wonb.gif).

How can this be done? If you know how it would be greatly appreciated, trying to get my head around this aspect of Javascript.

heres my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sinead19/72s9wfgy/2/

Comment: `Math.random() < 0.5`. The random number is between 0 and 1. So, almost 50% chance that the random number will be less than 0.5 or greater than 0.5. Assuming you know how to use css for styling and adding/removing css classes using javascript.

Comment: Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezzqqpcd/  just hit run multiple times to see it work

Comment: @Markai Thanks, for some reason it wont work when I put it into my text editor and save my html and load it on chrome, when I refresh it stays in same state

Comment: @user3594463 you should learn to inspect the variables using the console, you will then get a better idea why its working, why it doesn't, generally you need to play around.

Comment: I posted a complete html file structure as an answer for this specific fiddle so you can just copy it out of there and compare to your code

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like that. Using classes allows you to have multiple elements, with each having a random colour. Colours are defined in pure CSS.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("load", function() {
                var ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
                for(var i = 0 ; i < ps.length ; i++) {
                    var p = ps[i];
                    if(p.classList.contains("randomColour")) {
                        p.classList.add("randomColour" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2));
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .randomColour1 {
                color: blue;
                background-color: yellow;
            }
            .randomColour2 {
                color: red;
                background-color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Some Flow of Control</h1>
        <p class="randomColour">This text is a random combination of a foreground colour and background colour</p>
        <p class="randomColour">This text is a random combination of a foreground colour and background colour</p>
        <p class="randomColour">This text is a random combination of a foreground colour and background colour</p>
        <p class="randomColour">This text is a random combination of a foreground colour and background colour</p>
        <p>In this case it's black on white</p>
        <p> Signed </p>
        <img src="bonw.gif">
    </body>
</html>
```

To add more colours, replace the `2` (after `Math.random()`) by the number of colours schemes, and add the required class in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

All you really need here is a random toggle switch for two states.

Using the built-in `Math.random()` function to generate a random number between 0 and 1:

```
    var toggle_state = ( Math.random() > 0.5? true: false );
```

If the generated number is more than `0.5` we'll set the boolean to `true` otherwise, false`. In both cases, you would use the boolean`toggle_state` in the same way:

```
var img_src = ( toggle_state? image_path1 : image_path2 );
document.getElementById( "image_holder" ).src = img_src;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = ( toggle_state? "black" : "white" );
```

Every time this code is executed it will check to see if the seconds value is an even/odd number and change the image source accordingly.

This code assumes that your `<img>` element has an `id` attribute of `"image_holder"`.

### Here is an inline demo:

```js
var toggle_state = ( Math.random() > 0.5? true: false );

var img_src = ( toggle_state? "http://imgur.com/ovxadkg" : "http://imgur.com/TG2bbe5" ) + ".gif";
document.getElementById( "image_holder" ).src = img_src;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = ( toggle_state? "black" : "white" );
document.body.style.color = ( !toggle_state ? "black" : "white" );
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Some Flow of Control</h1>
  <p>This text is a random combination of a foreground colour and background colour</p>
  <p>In this case it's black on white</p>
  <p> Signed </p>
  <img id="image_holder" src="bonw.gif" />
</body>
```

Comment: @Lix thank you! I adapted your code into mine here, but it still wont work, do you know why? heres the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sinead19/ftj2ux80/

Comment: You can shorten your JS:  


`var toggle_state = new Date().getSeconds() % 2;`  


`var toggle_state = Math.random() > 0.5;`

Comment: @user3594463 - The background setting was being overridden by your original code and also the paths to the images were invalid. [I've fixed the jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ftj2ux80/1/).

Comment: @Lix It still wont work for some reason Ill add my updated code about in my original question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming not using JQuery, and you want an inline answer (changing styles on the JS page rather than calling a different CSS):

```
<html>
<title> Flow Test </title>
<body>

<p id="blackOrWhite" >This text is a random combination of a foreground colour and background colour</p>
<img id="image" src="bonw.gif">
<script>
  //hide image by default
  document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";

  if(Math.random() < 0.5){
     document.getElementById("blackOrWhite").style.color = 'white';
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
     document.getElementById("image").style.display = "inline";
  } // Else is the default(white background color and a black text color)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete html file structure for this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezzqqpcd/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .body1{
                background: white;
                color: black;
            }
            .body2{
                background: black;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Some Flow of Control</h1>
        <p>This text is a random combination of a foreground colour and background colour</p>
        <p>In this case it's black on white</p>
        <p> Signed </p>

        <img id="image" src="bonw.gif">
        <script>
            var rnd = Math.random();
            if(rnd < 0.5)
                document.querySelector("body").className = "body1";
            else{
                document.querySelector("body").className = "body2";
                document.getElementById("image").src = "wonb.gif";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this code set's two different classes for the body and set's the classname two either one of them depending on a random number

Comment: Thanks a million @Markai , this works :) Only thing that im trying to figure out now is how to get my image to change also? I have another image named wonb.gif, what code would I use to make this work for body2?